# How to receive webhooks from Microsoft's dynamics CRM using javascript(node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamics-crm, webhooks, asp.net-webhooks

I'm trying to develop an integration using node.js to receive webhooks from Microsoft's Dynamics CRM.

I find a lot of code snippets, blogs and so on for asp.net. But I could not find a way to implement it using javascript which is obviously using node.js.

Can anyone help me figure out?

Comment: Is [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/?platform=nodej) applicable?

Comment: Yes @greybeard, Azure comes with Dynamics right? If so, then yes

Answer (score 1):

From your question and comment's it not clear if you understand the Dynamics CRM platform.

- Out of the box CRM does not provide web hooks.
- Dynamics CRM does not come with Azure.
- If you are using CRM Online it is hosted by Microsoft on Azure, but you don't get access to Azure in that way.
- Node.js within the CRM infrastructure isn’t really a supported thing.

You will need build functionality to post webhooks from CRM, you can then build your Node.js web app to receive them.

Have a read of [Extend Microsoft Dynamics 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327974.aspx) this will give you an idea of the different ways you can change CRM. Also check out [Sending WebHooks with Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2016/01/15/sending-webhooks-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm/) which would appear to answer your question.